# Fazer busca ao banco de dados e exibir com while

Tags: php

Bom no caso, a minha pergunta é a seguinte, eu faço um select ao banco de dados com os critérios que quero que tenha. Como posso depois fazer um while para mostrar esses resultados, que foram buscar ao banco de dados.

Obrigado.

Comment: Coloca ai o ´codigo que vc tem

Comment: Acho que o será necessário while. Posta o código que você ja desenvolveu.

Comment: Depende de como está seu código da busca. O único jeito de responder é você colocando seu código mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isso?

```
$query = "SELECT...";
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

while($dado = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ // Enquanto houver dados ficará em loop
   $a = $dado['coluna1']; //recupera o dado do array
   $b = $dado['coluna2'];
   echo $a."-".$b."<br><br>"; //exibe o dado
}
```

Comment: Já agora para que serve o mysql_fetch assoc?

Comment: @Gonçalo
o `fetch_assoc()`, faz a mesma coisa que o `fetch_array()`, a diferença é que com o `fetch_array()` você pode indicar o índice da consulta pelo nome da coluna da base de dados ou pelo numero do índice do array, já  o `fetch_assoc()`,  é somente pelo nome da coluna. Lembrando que essas funções estão obsoletas no PHP 7.

Comment: Diga me o que significa a variavel $dado no parametro while

Comment: `$dado` é um array, ela vai receber as linhas da sua tabela do banco de dados, a cada loop do `while` ela recebe uma nova linha

Answer (score -1):

Sua pergunta é muito abrangente, primeiro pesquise como funciona para buscar os dados, segue um link de referêrencia:

http://pt-br.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson20.php

Então, caso tenha alguma dúvida poste aqui.

Abraço

Comment: Amigo eu sei utilizar a funcionalidade mysql fetch array, só não sei é como através disso consiga mostrar todos os dados desse select, porque por exemplo se eu fizer um select where idades="25", pode haver varias idades com 25 anos e eu quero mostrar os dados dessas pessoas todas com idades iguais a 25 anos.

Comment: Pelo que quer o SELECT está coreto `select where idades="25"`, não entendi