# Codeigniter - Recuperar categorias do banco

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho uma tabela ''categoria'' no banco de dados e a mesma possui a coluna 'id' e 'titulo', estou recuperando o mesmo em vários menu's dropdown, porém carrega todas as categorias do banco mas eu gostaria de carregar cada categoria em seu respectivo menu, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já, muito obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<ul>
  <li class="drop-menu">
    <span class="menu-item">Teste 1 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <?php
          foreach($categorias as $categoria){
      ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url
        ('categoria/'.$categoria->id.'/'.limpar($categoria->titulo)) ?>"><?php echo $categoria->titulo ?></a></li>
      <?php
          }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="drop-menu">
    <span class="menu-item">Teste 2 <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <?php
          foreach($categorias as $categoria){
      ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url
        ('categoria/'.$categoria->id.'/'.limpar($categoria->titulo)) ?>"><?php echo $categoria->titulo ?></a></li>
      <?php
          }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você poderia informar as queries que você faz para gerar essa array $categorias ?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você precisaria na verdade gerar cada 'li' da tabela pelo próprio php usando o loop while:

```
    $query = "select * from sua_tabela where seus_parametros";
    try {
        $result = $connect->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $count = $result->rowCount();
        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($categoria= $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                ?>
                <li class="drop-menu">
                    <span class="menu-item"><?php echo $categoria->titulo; ?><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url('categoria/'.$categoria->id.'/'.limpar($categoria->titulo)) ?>"><?php echo $categoria->titulo ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>    
            <?php
            }
        }
    } catch (PDOException $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
```

Note que usei PDO para a conexão e para a consulta, se estiver usando mysqli faça as alterações necessárias.

Comment: Eu realmente uso mysql, mas eu não sei fazer essas alterações, sou iniciante com banco de dados e php, estou fazendo um curso de codeigniter pela udemy e no curso não é explicado essa dúvida que me surgiu durante o mesmo, onde eu deveria fazer essas alterações? Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Eu não uso o mysqli, dê uma olhada nesse outro post: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119413/fazer-busca-ao-banco-de-dados-e-exibir-com-while), é só adaptar o que está no código que eu te passei usando a query do mysql, mas sugiro fortemente que use PDO ao invés de mysqli, pois usa o (prepare) que otimiza os preocessos entre servidos-cliente e traz ainda mais segurança que o mysqli, quando tiver um tempo pesquise mais sobre isso.